# How is DISCID made in cue sheet files?

Tags: music

We have for example REM DISCID D00DA810 from [wikipedia entry](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Cue_sheet). How is it calculated/where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the DiscID howto that you can find here : http://ftp.freedb.org/pub/freedb/misc/freedb_howto1.07.zip,

> The disc ID is an 8-digit hexadecimal (base-16) number, computed using
>   data from a CD's Table-of-Contents (TOC) in MSF (Minute Second Frame)
>   form.

This document includes a description of the algorithm used to compute the DiscID of a given audio CD.

Comment: Thanks! Wikipedia also has this info explained in a less-technical fashion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CDDB&oldid=863501500#Example_calculation_of_a_CDDB1_(FreeDB)_disc_ID).